# Routing problem when application is starting Ionic 4

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

We are developing an application with Ionic 4 with the framework Angular. 
We have an issue when we log to the application.

You can see the error on the picture:

[image: Picture error]
My code is here:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'tab1',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'tab2',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'tab3',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: '../tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/tabs/tab2',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tabs/tab2',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

I don't believe in magic but when i delete one dot on the loadchildren exemple :

> ../tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule -> ./tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule

I do it on all the loadchildreds I'm saving the page I try to log in, same problem
and after I reput the dot like this

> ./tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule -> ../tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule

I'm saving, I try to log in again and it works fine. With this problem, we can't compile on ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to resolve relative paths for your tabs. Use augury chrome to check and resolve your routing. Also try to simplify your routing.

```
{
    path: 'tab2',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
},
```